# Layout of multiplots with coord_fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can you align the plots in the example, so they align by top?
This is ONLY a problem because I use coord_fixed (but I need to).

My two (small) text labels show up as they should, but the two plots are placed in the vertical center of the cell.

I have looked and googled and I'm giving up...

Edited to reflect the problem/solution discussed below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

plot1b = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio=5)
plot2b = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio=5) +
  facet_wrap( ~ cyl, ncol=2)

g1 = ggplotGrob(plot1b + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),'cm'), plot.background = element_rect(fill="red")))
g2 = ggplotGrob(plot2b + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),'cm'), plot.background = element_rect(fill="red")))
t1 = arrangeGrob(g1,left = textGrob("A", y=1, vjust=1, gp=gpar(fontsize=7, fontface="bold")))
t2 = arrangeGrob(g2,left = textGrob("B", y=1, vjust=1, gp=gpar(fontsize=7, fontface="bold")))
f1 = arrangeGrob(t1,t2, ncol=2)

g1 = ggplotGrob(plot1b + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,8,0),'cm'), plot.background = element_rect(fill="red")))
g2 = ggplotGrob(plot2b + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,8,0),'cm'), plot.background = element_rect(fill="red")))
t1 = arrangeGrob(g1,left = textGrob("A", y=1, vjust=1, gp=gpar(fontsize=7, fontface="bold")))
t2 = arrangeGrob(g2,left = textGrob("B", y=1, vjust=1, gp=gpar(fontsize=7, fontface="bold")))
f2 = arrangeGrob(t1,t2, ncol=2)

f3 =arrangeGrob(f1,f2,ncol=2)

plot(f3)
ggsave(plot=f3, file="plot.png")
```

[image]

Comment: I've added the proper packages for you.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't check the top of my rather long analysis. I guess I can hack it by trying different width= and height= when using ggsave - but that is really not very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (the panels are aligned, but not including the facet strips)

[image],

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio=1)+ theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))
p2 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
  facet_wrap( ~ cyl, ncol=2) + theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))

g1 = ggplotGrob(p1 )
g2 = ggplotGrob(p2)

g <- egg::ggarrange(p1, p2,ncol=2, draw = FALSE)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, list(textGrob("A"), textGrob("B")), t = 1, l=c(1,4), z=-Inf)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Thanks - this is better than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question. I added a large bottom margin on each plot to push them to the top. (note that it isn't actually squashed as it appears in this image)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

plot1b = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio=1)+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,12,0),'cm'))
plot2b = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
  facet_wrap( ~ cyl, ncol=2)+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,12,0),'cm'))

g1 = ggplotGrob(plot1b)
g2 = ggplotGrob(plot2b)
t1 = arrangeGrob(g1,left = textGrob("A", y=1, vjust=1, gp=gpar(fontsize=7, fontface="bold")))
t2 = arrangeGrob(g2,left = textGrob("B", y=1, vjust=1, gp=gpar(fontsize=7, fontface="bold")))
f1 = arrangeGrob(t1,t2, ncol=2)

plot(f1)
```

[image]

Comment: You did understand it - but the solution doesn't really work - since it requires that you set the margin by trial and error - and in this case it is easier for me to just set the output height (ggsave) by trial and error.

Comment: Maybe it is just me - but I thought there would be an option for aligning plots within cells when using arrangeGrob()

Comment: I should probably explain - setting the margin to high results in both plots to be aligned at the top - but now they are getting to narrow - and are aligned in the center horizontally.

Comment: @pallevillesen grid.arrange is based on gtable, and gtable doesn't really provide a way to justify a grob within a cell. Another compounding issue is the way fixed aspect ratios constrain grid layouts – I've never been able to really figure this out, and I suspect I'm not the only one. That being said, the egg package on github might be a starting point (see my answer, not quite what you want though)